# Conditional Validator on Change

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-orm

I have a conditional validator on a domain field that uses the getPersistentValue gorm method.

```
class User {
    def notNull = ConditionalValidators.teamChangeValidator.curry('team', [NOT_NULLABLE]) 
    String team nullable: false, blank: false
    String impact nullable: true, validator: notNull
}

class ConditionalValidators {
    static String NOT_NULLABLE = 'notNullable'
    static notNullable = { fieldValue ->
        return fieldValue != null
    } 

    static teamChangeValidator = { team, listOfConstraints, fieldValue, userInstance->
        def result = true

        if(userInstance[team].id != userInstance?.getPersistentValue(team)?.id) {
            listOfConstraints.each { constraint ->
            result &= this[constraint](fieldValue)
        }

        return result ?: ['teamChangeValidator', team.capitalize()]
        } 
    }
}
```

But I cannot unit test this Domain class anymore because I am unable to mock out getPersistentValue

I have tried:

```
    User.metaClass.static.getPersistentValue = { fieldValue ->
        return null
    }
```

And:

```
    User.metaClass.getPersistentValue = { fieldValue ->
        return null
    }
```

But both have failed. I get a NullPointerException on getPersistentValue. This is especially troublesome because it is causing all my test cases to fail, and there doesn't seem to be a work around.

Comment: My guess is the userInstance object being passed in is not necessarily a user object instance.  Try adding a debug statement and checking the clazz...

Comment: Good point, but it is a user instance. I think it might have something to do with this jira: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7506 I can mock out isDirty but getPersistentValue is a pain.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions on perhaps stripping the conditional validator during my unit tests? Or any other way around this that is not commenting out around 74 unit tests?